# Python dictionary commands with dynamic functions?

Tags: python, django

New to Python/Django from PHP and am trying to wrap my head around these examples of update() and get() from this example:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-social-auth/0.3.0

`update()`: looks like it's doina jquery-ish type of update only for items that are enabled()... which I don't really get how that function comes out of the val.

```
            backends.update(((key, val)
                for key, val in sub.BACKENDS.items()
                    if val.enabled()))
```

And `get()`: Why does it have two sets of `()()`?

```
BACKENDS.get(name, lambda *args, **kwargs: None)(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`dict.update()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) can take an iterable of `(key, value)` pairs; the code you have there passes in a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) that produces such pairs. It loops over `sub.BACKENDS.items()` and for each pair only selects those whose `val.enabled()` method returns `True`. You could express it as a for loop as well:

```
for key, value in sub.BACKENDS.items():
    if value.enabled():
        backends[key] = value
```

The `dict.get()` function returns either the key or a default. Here the default is a anonymous function, a `lambda`. So the `BACKEND` dictionary either has a value for the key named in the `name` variable, or a lambda anonymous function is returned. Either way, the result of the `.get()` call is itself called. In Python, functions are first-class objects; you can store them in dictionaries too; if you retrieve one from a dictionary you can still call it:

```
>>> def foo(): print 'bar'
... 
>>> somedict = {'howdy': foo}
>>> somedict['howdy']()
bar
>>> somedict['howdy']
<function foo at 0x109ab9320>
>>> somedict.get('non-existent', 'not found')
'not found'
>>> somedict.get('howdy', 'not found')
<function foo at 0x109ab9320>
>>> somedict.get('howdy', 'not found')()
bar
```

So the extra `()` after `.get()` is applied to whatever `.get()` returned.

[Lambdas are anonymous functions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda) that can be defined in an expression (a `def functionname()` line is a statement and has to stand on it's own); lambdas thus can be defined while storing it into a dictionary directly:

```
>>> somedict = {'howdy': lambda: 'bar'}
>>> print somedict['howdy']()
bar
```

Comment: Thanks @Martijn, that was super helpful and detailed. One question, are there memory implications to putting a function call in the for loop ex. for key, value in sub.BACKENDS.items():

Comment: Aso, wasn't sure what this was <function foo at 0x109ab9320>

Comment: No, there are not. It's just a reference. `<function foo at 0x109ab9320>` is the representation string for that function object. CPython uses the memory address to help you detect different function objects (they'd be hard to keep apart otherwise).

Comment: Wow, you respond quick @Martijn. Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to write your example, but a bit more clear. see explanation in @Martijn Pieters' answer.

```
new_items = [(key, func) for key, func in sub.BACKENDS.items() if func.enabled()]
backends.update(new_items)

def do_nothing(*args, **kwargs):
    pass

func = BACKENDS.get(name, do_nothing)
func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks @Elazar. Also helpful to see this syntax for populating a dict.